# How do I modify a filepath using the os.path module?

Tags: python, filepath, self-modifying

My code

```
import os.path #gets the module

beginning = input("Enter the file name/path you would like to upperify: ")

inFile = open(beginning, "r") 
contents = inFile.read()
moddedContents = contents.upper() #makes the contents of the file all caps


head,tail = os.path.split(beginning) #supposed to split the path
new_new_name = "UPPER" + tail #adds UPPER to the file name
final_name = os.path.join(head + new_new_name) #rejoins the path and new file name

outFile = open(final_name, "w") #creates new file with new capitalized text 
outFile.write(moddedContents)
outFile.close()
```

I'm just trying to change the file name to add UPPER to the beginning to the file name via os.path.split(). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the point of calling `os.path.join` the way you do?

Comment: Of course I don't know if you are doing something wrong- you haven't even said what isn't working!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the name of a file path correctly in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748796/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-a-file-path-correctly-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` from `os.path.split` doesn't have a trailing slash in the end. When you join the `head` and `new_new_name` by concatenating them

```
head + new_new_name
```

you don't add that missing slash, so the whole path becomes invalid:

```
>>> head, tail = os.path.split('/etc/shadow')
>>> head
'/etc'
>>> tail
'shadow'
>>> head + tail
'/etcshadow'
```

The solution is to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) properly:

```
final_name = os.path.join(head, new_new_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
final_name = os.path.join(head + new_new_name)
```

to

```
final_name = head + os.sep + new_new_name
```